# Add header to response base on status code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to add a headers to response base on status code.
I used a ActionFilterAttribute, but OnResultExecuting method always return the status OK, becasue response didnt start yet.
And I could not add a header to OnResultExecuted because we culd not modify response.
Any idea where i can add a header?

```
public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        var httpContext = context.HttpContext;

        if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes.Status200OK)  // doesnt work since it is always 200
        {
            httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("flag1", "false");
```

Comment: you should do it on `OnResultExecuted` - executing happens before the action is invoked. i'd also consider doing this in a middleware, not an action filter.

Comment: if i add the header on OnResultExecuted, i will get exception: 'The response headers cannot be modified because the response has already started.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your returned result is a StatusCodeResult, you could may try the below :

```
 public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
 {
        var httpContext = context.HttpContext;

        if (context.Result is StatusCodeResult statusCodeResult &&
        statusCodeResult.StatusCode == 200)
        {
            httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("flag1", "false");
        }
  }
```

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you! Working perfect. The only one moment. `context.Result is ObjectResult`

Answer (score 0):

I will say you consider using a Middleware and do something like this

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(appBuilder =>
                {
                     appBuilder.Run(async context =>
                     {
                          var exceptionHandlerFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                          if (exceptionHandlerFeature != null)
                          {
                               var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Global exception logger");
                               logger.LogError(500,
                                   exceptionHandlerFeature.Error,
                                   exceptionHandlerFeature.Error.Message);
                          }
                          context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                          await context.Response.WriteAsync("An unexpected fault happened. Try again later.").ConfigureAwait(false);
                     });
                });
```

See if something like this works for your case. I hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately the same error when i'm using Middleware: The response headers cannot be modified because the response has already started. `public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next.Invoke(context);
                if (context.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status200OK)
                {
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("test", "false");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }`

Comment: Can you try moving your middleware into a class of its own and add extension method for it?